# How to search file name matching cell value from sharepoint using excel VBA code, and add value, if file not found creat new file

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, sharepoint

I am preparing checklist that needs to be update daily. Process is on pressing save button, macro should check the file name matching with cell value on sharepoint, if match found than open and update that file, if match not found create new file and paste whole data and save it as csv file. I am using below code but getting error on filename, I am not pro user of VBA, can you tell me what should I edit in this code?

```
    Sub Sync() 
Dim wkb As Workbook, wkb2 As Workbook 
Dim folderpath As String, filename As String, filename2 As String, FName As String, FileExt As String 
Dim LastRowSS As Integer, LastRowIn As Integer 
Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook folderpath = "https://Companycorp.sharepoint.com/sites/ServiceabilityOperations/Shared Documents/Self QC" & "/" 
FName = Worksheets("CheckList").Range("K2").Text 
filename = Dir(folderpath & FName) 
If 
filename = "" Then 
Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook 
Range("A9:E47").Select 
Selection.Copy Workbooks.Add 
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False 
Range("A1:A35").Select 
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select Application.CutCopyMode = False Application.CutCopyMode = False 
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C" 
Range("A1").Select 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:= _ "https://Companycorp.sharepoint.com/sites/ServiceabilityOperations/Shared%20Documents/Self%20QC" & "/" & FName _ , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False 
ActiveWindow.Close 
Else 
Range("E10:E47").Copy 
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open(folderpath & FName) 
wkb2.ActiveSheet.Range("E2").Select 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False 
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Try with UNC folder path ie. \\Companycorp.sharepoint.com\sites\ServiceabilityOperations\Shared Documents\Self QC\

Comment: Try to open the workbook using the predicted name and see if you get an error - if you do then likely it does not exist and you need to create it.